# A repeater to a VLAN

Tags: wireless-networking, vlan

I've bought a DLink DAP-1520 and wanted to set up the repeater. I managed to set it up at home which has no VLAN and connects directly to my router.

However, I need to set it up in the office. Our office is using Ubiquity.

Ubiquity is under VLAN 32, and carries three SSIDs which have their own VLANs.

My approach was to repeat the SSID that I wanted.

For some reason, it will work for 30 seconds, but then it disconnects for 30 seconds, and repeats in a cycle.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: Is this something that is approved by your IT dept.  Many wireless setups block rogue aps, which this would be.

Comment: Apology for the late reply. It is just a PoC. It is to prove to the management that a repeater is a bad way to go and buying extra/more AP is a better move.